# How to click on the download botton while exploring the PDF in IE11 through excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, automation, ie-automation

Sub Drop_Down()
Dim objIE As Object, ele As Object, opt As Object
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

```
objIE.Visible = True
objIE.navigate "https://isgs-oas.isgs.illinois.edu/reports/rwservlet?oil_permit_activity"

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

Set ele = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")

For Each opt In ele
    If opt.getAttribute("name") = "p_YEAR" Then
        opt.Focus
        opt.Value = "2018"
        Exit For
    End If
Next opt

Set ele = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("select")

For Each opt In ele
    If opt.getAttribute("name") = "p_MONTH" Then
        opt.Focus
        opt.Value = "January"
        Exit For
    End If
Next opt
objIE.document.forms(0).submit
Do While objIE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
```

***'Please help here
'Want to download the PDF file now***

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I constructed the URL by looping through months and years and converting those to strings, which I then concatenated to the base of the URL. I guessed on what year you wanted to start with, which you'll see in the "For year =" declaration.

[image: List of PDFs]

```
Sub DownloadFile()
Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Dim oStream As Object
Dim myURL As String
Dim LocalFilePath As String
Dim month As String
Dim year As Integer
Dim monthNo As Integer

For year = 2010 To 2018
    For monthNo = 1 To 12
        month = MonthName(monthNo)
            myURL = "https://isgs-oas.isgs.illinois.edu/reports/rwservlet?hidden_run_parameters=oil_permit_activity&p_MONTH=" & month & "&p_YEAR=" & CStr(year)
            LocalFilePath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\rwservlet\oil_permit_activity_" & month & "_" & CStr(year) & ".pdf"

                Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
                WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, "", ""  '("username", "password")
                WinHttpReq.send

                If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
                    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
                    oStream.Open
                    oStream.Type = 1
                    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
                    oStream.SaveToFile LocalFilePath, 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
                    oStream.Close
                End If
    Next monthNo
Next year
End Sub
```

The above code worked for me, but you have to make sure the folder "rwservlet" exists on your desktop or it'll throw an error (I'm not good at error handling, but we're all learning). Otherwise you can change the LocalFilePath string.

Comment: It's perfectly working in my system also... Thanks a lot for the response. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the names of the query parameters, you can build your URL automatically. I used Chrome's inspector to find the URL for the example above ("https://isgs-oas.isgs.illinois.edu/reports/rwservlet?hidden_run_parameters=oil_permit_activity&p_MONTH=January&p_YEAR=2018").

You could rework your script to automatically build a URL from parameters and then use one of the several "save file from URL" scripts that are out there. Here's one I found here on SE:
[Downloading a file in VBA and storing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29367130/downloading-a-file-in-vba-and-storing-it)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. But here I am facing a problem, the URL does not mention a file type. So whenever I download from URL, the file type become unknown & then I have to change the file type(e.g. PDF). Please help me to resolve the issue & also I want to change the name of the according to the year & county.