# Using WScript with MS Edge to download multiple files leaves open Edge tabs

Tags: excel, vba, wscript.shell

I am using a Wscript shell to automate the download of multiple (Excel files). The shell command creates a new tab (and popup window) in MS Edge for every download. What I would like is to create a new instance of Edge, and close it when I have finished.

The set-up: I have a third-party company that emails me links with which to download Excel files. If I click on the link in the email, a file is downloaded as a Protected View in Excel. The Excel file is produced by the server on the fly.

To automate this, I have a VBA routine that cycles through a list of these links (which I have separately extracted from my email), and I am using a Wscript shell object to drive Edge.

Code extract:

```
Dim wsh As New WshShell

Dim strCmd As String
strCmd = "microsoft-edge:"

Dim strLink As String
strLink = "https:\\somesite\\someserverprocess"    

wsh.Run strCmd & strLink, WaitOnReturn:=True
```

This code does the job of downloading the file into Excel, but leaves a new tab and a popup window in Edge for each file. Since I will be looping this over multiple files, I will have a lot of tabs and popups left at the end. I am hoping to create a process I can leave to run unattended, so really need to tidy up once this process is finished.

I have read several other questions on this topic on SO (in particular the lack of a COM automation interface for Edge), but without finding an answer. I am open to suggestions. While I am not wedded to Wscript as the method, my preference is to run this process from Excel VBA (as I have to process the actual Excel files as a second step).

Answer (score 0):

This answer might help
[Downloading a file in VBA and storing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29367130/downloading-a-file-in-vba-and-storing-it)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am following the "download a file" using Microsoft.XMLHTTP. My request comes back with status 401 ("unauthorized"). Which makes sense as the site has user control. One of the commenters on your answer alluded to this, and seemed to have a solution (though tantalizingly short of detail). When I use the WScript via Edge, the browser already has an authentication cookie, so I go straight to the file.

Comment: I've never had to pay credentials with XMLHTTP, but a quick search gives plenty of helpful results one of which should do the trick. :-). https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Xmlhttp+login